# Equivalent adjective of 'thirsty' in Russian

Tags: прилагательные, лексикон, одним-словом

When you're hungry, you say

> Я голоден.

When you're thirsty you say

> Мне хочется пить.

Is there an *adjective* in Russian that means thirsty? Perhaps derived from жажда (thirst)?
Has there ever been such an adjective in Russian?

Comment: This is very similar to the case in Spanish. There are words for "hungry" and "thirsty" (*hambriento* and *sediento*) but you never hear them. The nouns for "hunger" and "thirst" are used with the verb "to have" (*tener*).

Comment: hippietrail: Well, the strange thing in Russian is that hungry is used a lot, but no word for thirsty. That is a strange disparity

Comment: After consuming too much alcohol, you could say next morning: "У меня [*сушняк*](https://encrypted.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=%D1%81%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BA&tbs=imgo:1)" (noun, colloquial) to describe that you are thirsty due to alcohol consumption and it happens regularly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can say `жажден`, but it's rarely encountered outside of theological texts and older literature.

[Архиеп. Платон. Поучительныя слова. Том II](http://www.stsl.ru/lib/platon2/10.php)

> Тот, который безсмертною истинны пищею насыщал человеческий род, был
>   гладен, и **жажден** чрез все течение лет своих.

[Описание земли Камчатки. Том второй](http://az.lib.ru/k/krasheninnikow_s_p/text_0080.shtml)

> Сыт, касину.
>    Голоден, исиаре.
>    **Жажден**, ипекрейке.
>    Есть, ишама.
>    Пить, кпекреигиуа.

[Д.С. Лихачев - Смех как мировоззрение - "Смеховой мир" Древней Руси.](http://philologos.narod.ru/smeh/smeh-lihach.htm)

> Пословицы и поговорки также часто представляют собой юмор, глум: [...] Алчен в кухарне, **жажден** в пивоварне, а наг, бос в мылне

Overall, this word is very archaic and almost never used.

Comment: Thanks, could you perhaps also provide a quote from the bible that uses the word?

Comment: Yep, sure, will do right away.

Comment: Not necessarily from the Bible. I mean, just any quote of the usage, you know,

Comment: I'd like to emphasize that this word is archaic and is never used in colloquial language.

Comment: Кстати, а как будет женский род этого прилагательного? Жаждна?

Comment: Относительно не по теме: в тексте архиепископа не используется буква «ё» (и, соответственно, в вашей цитате «чрез все течение»). Это дореформенное (типа «житие мое») или современно-ленивое?

Comment: Being a native speaker, I've never ever heard or have seen that word in any context.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan most likely. I've never seen this word, and probably there's some historic peculiarity about it (if it even exists), but what you're proposing seems perfectly legit.

Answer (score 7):

While other replies do provide some workarounds, none of those can be actually used as a direct equivalent of “I'm thirsty” in a modern spoken Russian language, the most suggested reply uses archaic examples those would not be understood by modern Russians. So, “Я хочу пить” is the most correct translation.

Answer (score 2):

*Sorry – it’s not really an on-topic answer, but about-topic notes.*

There’s one thing about `голод/голодный` and `жажда/?`.
The former are ‘real’ Russian words, i. e. of East Slavic origin. The latter are of Church Slavonic origin. In the depths of language history Church Slavonic passages in Russian speech had been used (strictly) for ‘high style’ texts, i. e. in texts about divine, spiritual things, never about ‘low’ earthly subjects. The difference can be seen in modern

> `голодать` — not to eat (*physiologically*),
>   `жаждать`  —  to crave (*for something unmaterial as a rule*).

Anyway, both Church Slavonic `жажден` and Russian `жаден` discontinued to be actual as denoting *‘thirsty’* by now. (See Quassnoi’s comment below.)

NB. It is just my note concerning… Not a 'warranted' scientific conclusion.

---

**undate**
There’s another difference between `голод` and `жажда` (and their derivatives).

> `голод` is about *deprivation* of something, 'outer' objective situation,
>   `жажда` is to mean a (strong) *want* for something,  'inner' subjective situation.

Though, I have no idea if this difference is related somehow with the previous one and how it could (if could) result in the situation in question.

Comment: The Russian participle did not disappear, it changed meaning: *жадный* now means "greedy", not "thirsty".

Answer (score 1):

If you replace your request

> Я голоден.

with

> У меня голод.

Than `thirsty` will be:

> У меня жажда.

As Philip Seyfi noticed: `жажден` - `archaic and almost never used.`

> Я жажден.

Nobody use this sentence.

Comment: Welcome to Russian Language beta! This is an old question and your answer does not add new information to already existing ones. Do you have something more to add?

Comment: I'm apologize, this is only 12th page of question. Russian Language doesn't looks like Stackoverflow or Ubuntu. http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions?page=12&sort=newest Sorry me.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* say `Я пересох`, "I'm all dried up", but that's rather colloquial.

Comment: Well, you actually can, as it said in russian, кто ж запретит, but this is very not common. "Хочу пить" is waaaay more common. Они пересохли? Она пересохла? I doubt, I doubt.

Answer (score 0):

жажден, though relatively rarely used, does mean 'thirsty' and it is used both literally and metaphorically, as for example:

Лев алчен и волк жажден, иже тиранствует, нищь сый, над языком убогим.

Comment: Your example doesn't sound Russian (at least it is far from modern Russian).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an adjective in Russian that means thirsty?

There are phrase depending on context and style. But the adjective in one word I can't find out.

1. Когда обыватель сообщает кому-то свою потребность в воде в обычной речи: (с акцентом или метафорой) `Жажда одолела.`, `Жажда замучила.`, `Пить хочу.`, `Сушняк замучал.` или `Сушняк!`; (когда что-то препятствует) `Попить бы.`, `Пить хочется.` или `Сейчас бы воды.`.
2. Описание  от третьего лица чьего-то желания напиться воды: (лит.) `Он жаждал воды.`, `Томимый жаждой, он ...`(склонился над ручьём, напр.), `Замученный жаждой, он...` (не мог отказать кому-то, напр.), `Он испытывал сильную жажду.`; (в обычном разговоре) `Он пить хочет.` (воды); (с акцентом и/или метафорой) `Его жажда замучила.`.
3. При описании состояния организма от третьего лица в экстремальной ситуации: `Он сильно обезвожен.` (потому что долго не пил). Не путать это `обезвожен` с `dehydrated`, описывающее результат воздействия на материал (в научном контексте), хотя в обоих случаях речь о сильно пониженном содержании воды по сравнению с нормой.

Answer (score -1):

Я обезвожен.
i.e. My body has lost a lot of water.

Comment: This is not a synonym for "thirsty".

Comment: Т.е. желание потребления воды не является результатом постепенного обезвоживания организма?

Comment: do you know what synonym means? "Dehydrated" and "thirsty" are different words, with close but different meanings. An unconscious person in a desert is dehydrated but not thirsty. A drunkard seeking for a drink is thirsty but not dehydrated.

Comment: Какой был изначально вопрос? Я его понял как необходимость выражения одним словом русского языка (современного) физиологической потребности человека потребления воды. По аналогии с потребностью потребления еды. Если к вам подойдет человек и скажет "Я обезвожен" или "Я обезвоженный" - вы его не поймете?

Comment: The question was how to translate "thirsty" with an adjective. "Thirsty" is not the same as "dehydrated", in the same way "hungry" (*голодный*) is not the same as "malnourished" (*истощённый*), though they are very close of course. You cannot apply "thirsty" or "hungry" to a plant or something else which lacks consciousness in other than metaphorical sense. In the same way you can't apply "dehydrated" or "malnourished" to a person who wants to eat or drink despite the lack of need: "he's always hungry despite being fat / *он хоть и жирён, но всегда голоден*".

Answer (score -2):

`Жаждущий`, however it is not quite adjective.

> Земля, жаждущая дождя.
>
> Цветок, жаждущий воды.
>
> Село, жаждущее хорошего председателя :)

Comment: Но ведь слово "жаждущий" означает "желающий" и с потребностью пить не совсем связано. Я неправ?

Comment: По крайней мере предложение "Я жаждущий." бессмысленно, если не неправильно.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan You are absolutely right and the third example (село) shows this case. If you speak about yourself you can say "Я жажду"

Comment: Разве "Я жажду" означает, что я хочу пить? По-моему, "жаждить" переходный глагол, и фраза "Я жажду" требует прямого дополнения. Нет?

Comment: "Жаждать". Краткости ради я не указал дополнение, хотя оно должно быть указано явно либо быть известно из контекста. "Ты обещал мне букет! Я жажду его увидеть, в конце концов!"

Comment: Я бы тоже сказал что `жаждущий` означает `желающий` а не `кому хочется пить`, и ваши примеры это подтверждают. `Земля, жаждущая дождя`, это земля которая хочет дождя, а не земля которая хочет пить. На английский язык я бы `жаждущий` перевёл как `hungry`, скорее чем `thirsty`

Comment: @PhilipSeyfi Если обратить внимание на *современный* русский язык, то "жажден" можно встретить и в переносном смысле тоже. По пруфлинку много опечаток, но, тем не менее, использование в переносном смысле весьма заметно: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%22

Comment: @Armen: Даже если «жаждать» используется как синоним слова «желать», это не значит, что мы можем пренебречь этимологией, которая весьма прозрачна в этом примере.

Comment: @Philip: по-английски всё равно будет использовано «thirsty» в приведённом примере. Примитивное подтверждение: гугль находит [8300 результатов](http://www.google.com/#q=%22hungry+for+water%22&hl=ru&biw=1600&bih=778&fp=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&cad=b) по фразе «hungry for water» и [188000](http://www.google.com/#q=%22thirsty+for+water%22&hl=ru&biw=1600&bih=778&fp=71af07a39d7f4b56&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&cad=b) по фразе «thirsty for water».

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: The verb жаждать can be used as an equivalant of  I am thirsty. But it is an old-fashioned word and is  hardly ever  used in everyday speech. The most common way to say I am thirsty in Russian is Я хочу пить. You can make sure of it if you consult an English -Russian dictionary. There is not any anjective from the verb жаждать in Russian.